# Pass data from one directive to another

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive that uses custom template, and I would like to pass the data from that directive to another one, and looking for the best possible way. So, I would like when the data inside the directive one changes, directive two get notified(watcher?), and acts upon it. So far, only the method with controller inside the directive one, and a watcher inside directive two for the controller method(from directive one) makes sense. Is there a a better way for this ?

```
--------------           --------------
| directive 1 |---data-->| directive 2 |
|             |          |             |
---------------          --------------
```

Comment: use same data (object pointer) on both directives. and watch changes.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the [$broadcast](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope) on the rootScope:

On the first directive:

```
$rootScope.$broadcast("NEW_EVENT", data);
```

On the other directive:

```
scope.$on("NEW_EVENT", function(event, data){
           //use the data
        });
```

Take a look at this [Understanding Angular’s $scope and $rootScope event system $emit, $broadcast and $on](http://toddmotto.com/all-about-angulars-emit-broadcast-on-publish-subscribing/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use either $broadcast or services

```
$rootScope.$broadcast("anotherDirective");
```

if you want to use values of one directive into another 
then

```
angular.module('app',[]).directive('directOne',function(serviceOne){
 return {
        restrict: 'A',

        link: function (scope, el, attrs) {
serviceOne.variable1=anyValue;
}
}
});
```

second directive

```
angular.module('app',[]).directive('directSec',function(serviceOne){
 return {
        restrict: 'A',

        link: function (scope, el, attrs) {
console.log(serviceOne.variable1);
}
}
});
```