# How can I Pass One Value from One Directive to Another?

Tags: angularjs

I have two input fields that have the **datetimepicker** directive.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <label for="trainingStartDate">Start (Date and Time)</label>
        <input name="trainingStartDate"
               ng-model="Training.Start"
               id="trainingStartDate"
               datetimepicker
               class="form-control" />
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <label for="trainingEndDate">End (Date and Time)</label>
        <input name="trainingEndDate"
               ng-model="Training.End"
               id="trainingEndDate"
               datetimepicker
               class="form-control" />
    </div>
</div>
```

The datetimepicker is implemented as follows:

```
.directive('datetimepicker',
    function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            require: 'ngModel',
            scope: { 'ngModel': '=' },
            link: function (scope: ng.IScope, element: ng.IAugmentedJQuery, attributes: ng.IAttributes, controller: any) {
                    element.datetimepicker({
                        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
                        timeFormat: 'hh:mm TT',
                        minDate: 0,
                        hourMax: 23,

                        onSelect: function (datetime) {
                            controller.$setViewValue(datetime);
                            controller.$render();
                            scope.$apply();
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Basically what this directive does is that it opens a date and time picker object and sets the date and time to the viewValue (in this case it is Training.Start and Training.End) upon selection.

Now my problem is that when I try to add another directive named greaterThan to the **trainingEndDate** input, I get an error that my two directives both cannot have isolated scopes.

```
<div class="col-xs-6">
    <label for="trainingEndDate">End (Date and Time)</label>
    <input name="trainingEndDate"
           ng-model="Training.End"
           id="trainingEndDate"
           datetimepicker
           greater-than="{{ Training.Start }}"
           class="form-control" />
</div>
```

This is how the greaterThan directive is implemented:

```
.directive('greaterThan',
    function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            require: 'ngModel',
            scope: { 'ngModel': '=' },
            link: function (scope: ng.IScope, element: ng.IAugmentedJQuery, attributes: ng.IAttributes, controller: any) {
                var validate = function (viewValue) {

                    if (!viewValue || !attributes.greaterThan) {
                        controller.$setValidity('greaterThan', true);
                    }
                    else {
                        var startDate = new Date(eval(attributes.greaterThan));
                        var endDate = new Date(viewValue);

                        controller.$setValidity('greaterThan', endDate > startDate);
                    }

                    return viewValue;
                };

                controller.$parsers.unshift(validate);
                controller.$formatters.push(validate);

                attributes.$observe('greaterThan', function (comparisonModel) {
                    return validate(controller.$viewValue);
                });
            }
        }
    });
```

Is it possible for me to implement both of these directives in my input field? I need the greaterThan directive to check if the viewValue (Training.End) is less than the Training.Start date. Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Sure, remove `scope: { 'ngModel': '=' },` from both. You don't need it; requiring `'ngModel'` includes it already. That will remove the isolated scope. If you must pass things between two directives, that's been [asked and answered](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30452660/215552) (many times actually).

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much!